# send parameter between jsp and servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I need to send parameters from jsp to servlet but to update only one row not all the rows generated by servlet.
Can you help me with this?
My code for the servlet is:

```
public class ExcelTest extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        //out.println(request.getParameter("customerName"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++){
            out.println("<input + id = " + i + " type=\"text\" value = " + request.getParameter("customerName") + ">");
            request.setAttribute("vvv", i);
            out.println("<a href=\"http://localhost:8079/TesteExcel/createparameters.jsp\">Visit</a>");
            out.println("<div>");            
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){                
                out.print("<div id = " + i + "" + j + " style=\"width:100px; float:left\">" + i + " - " + j +"</div>");
            }
            out.println("</br>");
            out.println("</div>");
        }
    }
}
```

and for the jsp is:

```
<form name="excel" action="ExcelTest" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="customerName">
            <input type="text" name="customerCUI">
            <input type=submit value="click me">

</form>
```

Thank you,
Coco

Comment: The info is incomplete.Please provide more information so we can help.What parameter you want to send ?Did u try to store it in session?

Comment: I am trying to send the "customerName", from jsp page, parameter to "out.println("<input + id = " + i + " type=\"text\" value = " + request.getParameter("customerName") + ">");" line from servlet. the problem is that it will send in each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
         String custName = request.getParameter("customerName");
            for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++){
                if(i!=0)
                    custName="";
                out.println("<input + id = " + i + " type=\"text\" value = " + custName + ">");
                request.setAttribute("vvv", i);
                out.println("<a href=\"http://localhost:8079/TesteExcel/createparameters.jsp\">Visit</a>");
                out.println("<div>");            
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){                
                    out.print("<div id = " + i + "" + j + " style=\"width:100px; float:left\">" + i + " - " + j +"</div>");
                }
                out.println("</br>");
                out.println("</div>");
            }
```

For first iteration only,it will take `customer name`.

Here I am assuming that you need that `input` tag in each iteration.

Comment: yes, I need the input tag in each iteration. the idea is that when I press the "visit" link the change to be available only for that link not for all input tags.

Comment: you want visit link once?

Comment: no, I need that from the jsp to update only one tag not all the input tags. the tag that I want to update is the tag with the link I choose. At the moment when I generate the html from the servlet I change all the tags